# I think I need a value (?) but only identifier (??) works in my knex.raw statement. Bug or flawed understanding?

Tags: knex.js

Since the final map in the arguments to `raw` is returning 0s, i.e. values, I would expect the final map in the INSERT clause below to be `${columnNames.map(() => '?').join(',')` not `${columnNames.map(() => '??').join(',')`. However, that fails with a SQL error and the form as presented below succeeds. Is the form below actually correct? Or, is this a possible bug in knex?

```
await knex.raw('CREATE TRIGGER ?? AFTER INSERT ON ?? FOR EACH ROW ' +
               'BEGIN ' +
               `INSERT INTO ?? (??,${columnNames.map((key)=>'??').join(',')}) VALUES (??,${columnNames.map(() => '??').join(',')});` +
               'END;',
[`${table}_${name}_insert`,table,name,idColumn,...columnNames,`NEW.${idColumn}`,...columnNames.map(()=>0)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that your values are not all 0, one of them (the first one) is `NEW.${idColumn}`. If you use a single `?` for this then it will treat this as a string which is not what you want.

What you'll want to do is leave the first element of your `VALUES` as a double `??` (for the `NEW.${idColumn}`) and then change the subsequent ones to a single `?` (for the `0`s)

i.e.

```js
await knex.raw('CREATE TRIGGER ?? AFTER INSERT ON ?? FOR EACH ROW ' +
               'BEGIN ' +
               `INSERT INTO ?? (??,${columnNames.map((key)=>'??').join(',')}) VALUES (??,${columnNames.map(() => '?').join(',')});` +
               'END;',
[`${table}_${name}_insert`,table,name,idColumn,...columnNames,`NEW.${idColumn}`,...columnNames.map(()=>0)]);
```